# Show $f^{-1}(I)$ Ideal in $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

I'm trying to show that if $f: R \rightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism, and $I \subset S$ is ideal, then $f^{-1}(I)$ is Ideal in $R$

I'm trying to show that is satisfies the conditions of an ideal, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a different approach which is maybe simpler is to use the Homomorphism Theorem, and consider the composite morphism $f\circ g: R \rightarrow S \rightarrow S/I$, and then we have that $f^{-1}I$ is the kernel of this, therefore an ideal in $R$.

Answer (score 1):

A direct proof :

Note that $f^{-1}(I)$ is non-empty as it contains 0 (infact, the whole of ker f).

Suppose $x,y \in f^-1(I)$ and r in R.

Then, $f(x),f(y) \in I$ implies that $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y) \in I, f(rx) = f(r)f(x) \in I, f(xr) = f(x)f(r) \in I$ as $I$ is an ideal of S. Hence, $x+y, rx, xr \in f^{-1}(I)$.

So, $f^{-1}(I)$ is an ideal in R.

Comment: you need to replace the plus with a minus sign to ensure that $f^{-1}\left( I\right)$ is an actual subgroup of $R$, more precisely the minus sign ensures that the inverse of any element in $f^{-1}(I)$ is also contained in $f^{-1}(I)$.

Comment: The solution shows that $f^{-1}(I)$ is closed under addition and multiplication by ring elements. This is enough to ensure closedness under additive inverses. If x and y are in $f^{-1}(I)$, then x-y = x + (-1).y is in $f^{-1}(I)$ automatically.

Comment: Of course I assume that rings are equipped with multiplicative identity.

Comment: Ah yes you are right of course! I was thinking exclusively about the group structure. My mistake!